# Как справиться с адаптацией изображения height:100%;  в mozilla firefox?

Tags: html, firefox

```
#content img {
    border:solid 1px;
    border-color:#DBDBDB;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:2px;
    position:center;

}
<div id="content">
<img src="">
</div>
```

Comment: А что именно происходит с изображением в FireFox ?

Comment: ну как что, не работает height:100%;

Comment: @Bridun, `height: 100%` означает, что элемент заполнит высоту своего родителя. У Вас проблема в вёрстке

Comment: не проблема, а решить не могу проблему height:100%; выходит поза блок

Comment: @Bridun, тогда пишите более развёрнуто

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема возникает из-за padding, он делает высоту изображения 100% + 4px, напишите стили вот так и проблема должна решиться:

```
#content img {
    border:solid 1px;
    border-color:#DBDBDB;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:2px;
    position:center;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

С `box-sizing: border-box;` свойство `padding` будет входить в заданные 100%.

[Сделал пример в сравнении с border-box и без](http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/dry22nc9/) и для наглядности покрасил родительский элемент красным фоном, визуально видно, что в варианте без `border-box` изображение вылезает за блок.

Comment: Решил вопрос так: 


    // images auto class
    function add_image_responsive_class($content) {
       global $post;
       $pattern ="/<img(.*?)class=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)>/i";
       $replacement = '<img$1class="$2 img-responsive"$3>';
       $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
       return $content;
    }

    class="img-responsive" 

        height:100%;
        width:100%;

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function($){ //запускаем, когда документ загрузится
    $("#content").height($(window).height()); //меняем высоту дива на высоту окна в первый раз, т.к. событие просто при открытии не вызывается
    });
```